# Is it possible to get Audio duration with Zapier Code (Python) Step?

Tags: python, audio, zapier

is it possible to get the duration of an audio file with Zapier Code Step with Python or Javascript?

I have uploaded a file to google drive and now I need the duration of the file. If this is not possible with google drive files. As an alternative I can use Dropbox or Amazon AWS.

I have tried with the Zapier Code Step(Python):

```
import wave
import contextlib
fname = input.get('fileurl')
with contextlib.closing(wave.open(fname,'r')) as f:
    frames = f.getnframes()
    rate = f.getframerate()
    duration = frames / float(rate)
    output = print(duration)
```

But this doesn't work. I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 11, in the_function
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 510, in open
      return Wave_read(f)

    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 164, in
```

Comment: Why don't you calculate this before uploading the file and save it as metadata in a separate file (e.g. an xml file).

Comment: The step before is that the audio file is uploaded from a Formular with fileupload field using Ninjaforms(Wordpress) As I know ninjaform directly upload the file to the configured cloud (Google drive, Dropbox, Amazon AWS.) The zap is triggerd by  „new file in folder - Google drive“

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question! I thought it wouldn't be possible, but it turns out it is. Your code isn't working because the `fileurl` isn't a file name, so the library blows up (without a helpful error, unfortunately).

The trick is that `wave.open` expects a filename or a file-like object. `Code by Zapier` can't really use the filesystem, but we can create an in-memory "file" that we can feed into `wave`.

Try this:

```py
import wave
from io import BytesIO

# I pulled a file from 
# https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-wav-download/
# but you can use input_data['file_url'] or something instead

file_url = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav'

wave_resp = requests.get(file_url)
wav_file = BytesIO(wave_resp.content)

with wave.open(wav_file) as f:
    frames = f.getnframes()
    rate = f.getframerate()
    duration = frames / float(rate)
    return {'duration': duration}
```

For that test file, I get a `duration` of `33.529625`- my browser says it's ~ 33 second long, so that looks correct!